# How to change media capture photo resolution for UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-mobile

So I have some code that takes a photo in a UWP app (running on windows desktops and phones) using this code.

```
await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);
```

And it works great but it always takes the image at the full resolution of the device... (so 44 megapixels on a Lumia 1020) which is too big for me. I want to limit the resolution to a fixed size (say around 16 megapixel).

So is there a way of setting the camera capture resolution or will I have to capture it at full resolution and downscale it myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to change resolution of *MediaCapture* element by [setting MediaStreamProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh700895.aspx) just after initialization:

```cs
// initialization here

// get available resolutions
var resolutions = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).ToList();
// set used resolution
await captureManager.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, resolutions[1]);
```

Comment: This was perfect and has fixed my issue. Thanks for the concise and correct code, I don't know how I couldn't find this in the documentation.